# "New Task" not displaying on Salesforce Mobile and Lightning Experience Actions when added to the layout

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, page-layout, tasks, publisher-action

I have added "New Task" to the Opportunity layout as an action, however it is not displaying on the Opportunity record. I have also enabled the record type in the System Administrator profile from which I am viewing the record. Is there any guidance I can receive regarding displaying "New Task" as an action? Why is this not displaying when added to the page layout?

Comment: Does this help (https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000387864&type=1) ?